# Separable but not exact equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In class, my professor stated that all separable equations are exact, and we even proved it for homework, but I think I found an equation that is separable but not exact:

> $$(x\ln y+xy)+(y\ln x+xy)y′ =0$$

My Work:

\begin{align*}
  M &= x\ln y + xy \\
  M_y &= \frac{x}{y} +x \\
  N &= y\ln x + xy \\
  N_x &= \frac{y}{x} +y \\
  M_y &\neq N_x
\end{align*}

But
\begin{align*}
  x(\ln y + y) + y \times y'\times (\ln x +x) &= 0 \\
  x(\ln y + y) &= - y \times y'\times (\ln x +x) \\
  \frac{x}{\ln x +x} &= \frac{- y \times y'}{\ln y + y}
\end{align*}

Separated

So whats up? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement is that a separable differential equation **in the form**

$$ a(x)\; dx + b(y)\; dy = 0$$

is exact.  But if you multiply an exact differential equation by some function of $x$ and/or $y$, it generally will cease to be exact.
So, for example, $x a(x)\; dx + x b(y)\; dy = 0$ will not be exact, though it is still separable.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!